# Как обойтись без iPhone в app store

Tags: xcode, iphone

При создания архива в xCode требует наличие iPhone как я понимаю. Можно ли как-то обойтись без него? Ну очень не хочется мне покупать iPhone!

Ошибка выдаваемая в xCode:

Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.
No profiles for 'xx.xxxxxx' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'xx.xxxxxx'.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'

Comment: у тебя Хакинтош?

Comment: на виртуалке стоит os x

Comment: Зачем нужен архив?

Comment: Здесь написано как профиль создать https://www.genuitec.com/docs/archives/ios-application-provisioning-requirements/

Comment: Что именно Вы делаете?